# Does closing a fill impact performance?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In AS3 - after drawing into the graphics canvas of a DisplayObject using [beginFill()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginFill%28%29), does closing the fill
using [endFill()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#endFill%28%29) impact (improve) performance or memory consumption?

Or does it merely closes the fill so that you can start a new one elsewhere?

Comment: I've read (a long time ago) that `endFill()` is called for you automatically if you do not call it. As such there's no difference, and it's really only useful if you want to start drawing elsewhere. I would give this as a formal answer, but I cannot find the resource where I read this (Essential Actionscript, by Colin Moock perhaps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this methods a lot in intensive applications (videogames) and tried to learn about this too. I never noticed any differences so I would say it does not affect performance or memory consumption. I think it just changes a flag so that it doesn't fill other shapes you draw later.

However, I couldn't find any "official" sources confirming or denying this so I am not 100% positive. I'm sorry but this is the best answer I can give you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The AS3 reference says this about the `beginFill()` method:

---

**The application renders the fill whenever three or more points are drawn, or when the `endFill()` method is called.**

---

This hints that the `endFill()` method isn't completely necessary. However, if less than 3 points are drawn (i.e. if you only draw a line) it will not render the fill until you call `endFill()`. So generally, `endFill()` is basically used to render the fill, rather than close it off.
Still, the documentation of the `endFill()` method states:

---

**If the current drawing position does not equal the previous position specified in a `moveTo()` method and a fill is defined, the path is closed with a line and then filled.**

---

So it'd be best to use `endFill()` if the drawing depends on user input.

On the whole, I'd recommend to use `endFill()` whenever you're finished with `beginFill()`. This way you can make sure that your fill has completed properly. I've seen it used in every example I know that uses `beginFill()`, so even if it isn't necessary it's good practice. I doubt it affects performance noticeably, and if it does then it will probably improve it.

Comment: +1 for finding that reference about 3 or more points being drawn causing the fill to be rendered (ie: ended). I don't think it affects performance at all.

Comment: Thanks puggsoy, I read the manual before I used it as a link in my question. Nor the manual nor your answer answers my question.

Comment: Hmm yeah sorry about that, I don't really know much about the performance aspects of it.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek, I think it does answer the question. If you use `beginFill()` and draw more than 3 points, and don't use `endFill()` the fill is closed automatically. If you call `beginFill()` and draw an ellipse/rectangle, that graphic is also filled by default. Calling `endFill()` will not consume any more memory than not calling it, and in the ellipse/rectangle case, I think the performance difference would be the negligible (ie: the ellipse/rect is filled regardless). Someone might have to look at the Flash Player source to answer this w/100% certainty :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it doesn't call endfill(), still it renders a line.

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();

s.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
s.graphics.lineTo(200,150);
addChild(s);
```